# Como imprimir vetor formatado em Shell?

Tags: array, linux, bash, shell-script, shell

Estou tentando receber uma string e mudar apenas um dos valores dela, e isso é fácil utilizando vetores. Porém, ao imprimir a string, o vetor sai sem formatação, já tentei imprimir ele com aspas e mesmo assim ele continua com a formatação diferente da inicial, respeitando apenas a formatação da parte que eu mudei.

```
#!/bin/bash
STR="O    331  RATO    ROEU A  ROUPA      68.352  47.294  40.713  1.00 16.48    C"
IFS='  ' read -r -a array <<< "$STR"
if [ ${array[1]} -gt 99 ] && [ ${array[1]} -lt 999 ] 
then
    array[1]="      1"

fi
echo "${array[@]}"
```

A saída fica:

```
O       1 RATO ROEU A ROUPA 68.352 47.294 40.713 1.00 16.48 C
```

Porém eu preciso que a saída seja:

```
O       1  RATO    ROEU A  ROUPA      68.352  47.294  40.713  1.00 16.48    C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que, ao criar o array, você separa a string em vários elementos (um contendo o `O`, outro contendo `331`, etc), mas os espaços se perdem. Ao tentar imprimir o array novamente, não tem como ele saber quantos espaços tinham anteriormente (ele só vai imprimir os elementos, separando-os por um espaço).

Uma alternativa é não quebrar a string em um array, e extrair somente o trecho que você quer e substituí-lo:

```
#!/bin/bash
STR="O    331  RATO    ROEU A  ROUPA      68.352  47.294  40.713  1.00 16.48    C"
VAL=$(echo "$STR" | awk '{print $2}')
if [ $VAL -gt 99 ] && [ $VAL -lt 999  ] 
then
    STR=$(echo "$STR" | sed "s/${VAL}/      1/")
fi
echo "$STR"
```

O [`awk`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) quebra a string em várias partes, separadas por espaço, e permite que você manipule-as do jeito que precisar. No caso estou pegando somente a segunda parte (`print $2`), que corresponde ao `331`.

Em seguida eu testo o valor deste e faço a substituição na string original, usando [`sed`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/sed1.html), que troca o valor `331` pelo número 1 com vários espaços antes. Por fim, é só imprimir a string. O resultado é:

```
O          1  RATO    ROEU A  ROUPA      68.352  47.294  40.713  1.00 16.48    C
```

Note que o `sed` substituiu o `331` por "1 com vários espaços antes". Mas se quiser apenas trocar 331 por 1 e manter a mesma quantidade de espaços, bastaria fazer:

```
STR=$(echo "$STR" | sed "s/${VAL}/1/")
```

---

Outra maneira de fazer é usar [`grep`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html) para pegar ou os espaços, ou uma das "palavras" (qualquer coisa que não seja espaço), e ir concatenando as strings resultantes (substituindo apenas a que você precisa):

```
STR="O    331  RATO    ROEU A  ROUPA      68.352  47.294  40.713  1.00 16.48    C"
IFS=$'\n'
RES=""
i=1
for s in $(echo "$STR" | grep -oE ' +|[^ ]+')
do
    if [ $i -eq 3 ] && [ $s -gt 99 ] && [ $s -lt 999 ]
    then
        s='1'
    fi

    RES="$RES$s"
    i=$((i+1))
done
echo "$RES"
```

O `grep` usa a expressão regular `' +|[^ ]+'` (um ou mais espaços ou um ou mais caracteres que não são espaços), e retorna cada um desses trechos separadamente (primeiro o `O`, depois os espaços, depois o 331, os espaços, etc).

O `for` percorre esses resultados, mas eu tive que mudar o `IFS` para que ele considere a quebra de linha (`\n`) como separador, assim o `for` também considera os espaços como elementos na hora iterar pelos resultados.

Dentro do `for` eu substituo somente o campo que quero, e o restante permanece o mesmo (inclusive os espaços), e vou concatenando tudo na variável `RES`.

O resultado é o mesmo:

```
O    1  RATO    ROEU A  ROUPA      68.352  47.294  40.713  1.00 16.48    C
```